# Apply function on all values of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary that look like

```
d= {(1, 8): 94.825000000000003, (2, 8): 4.333}
```

I am trying to apply a function to round all the values.

I don't wanna re-create the dictionary.

```
newD= {}
for x,y in d.iteritems():
   newD+= {x:round(y)}
```

Is there any pythonic-way to apply `round` function on all values ?

Comment: your example doesn't actually work, also it seems like you are recreating the dictionary by making `newD` correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: It's not a duplicate. This is different

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a little more convoluted, but you did ask for a 'pythonic-way' ;)

```
newD = {k:round(v) for k, v in d.items()}
```

However, this dictionary comprehension will only work on 2.7+. If using an older version of Python, try this more convoluted way:

```
newD = dict(zip(d.keys(), [round(v) for v in d.values()]))
```

Let me unpack this a little bit:

- We are beginning by reassigning the new dictionary (`d`) object back to a new dictionary as requested (although you could easily assign it to the same name)
- The outer `dict()` ensures the final result is a dictionary object
- `zip()` returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences
- The first argument sequence given to `zip()` is the dictionary keys (`d.keys()`)
- The second argument sequence given to `zip()` is the rounded values after a list comprehension
- The list comprehension rounds each value in the dictionary values and returns a list of the rounded values

Comment: Or you could just write ``d = {k:round(v) for k, v in d.items()}``, but the question explicitly stated *"I don't wanna re-create the dictionary."*

Comment: @Bogdan good point, updated. Thanks!

Comment: elegant solution @Dan

Comment: I'm sorry this is not an elegant solution at all and definitely not pythonic. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29 
The 2nd code is perfectly fine though

Answer (score 8):

You could try something like this:

```
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    d[k] = round(v)
```

It will do an in-place rounding of all of the items in the dictionary. In this particular example it will work perfectly, however be careful - all normal caveats of using [the round function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) apply.

Comment: you are rounding one of the dictionary key tuple members, how can this be the answer?

Comment: @jamylak I'm sorry, I don't understand your question? I iterate through every key, value pair in the dictionary, calculate a new value and replace the old on in the dictionary.

Comment: No you aren't, you are just iterating keys. Try `print k, v` in your loop

Comment: @jamylak - bah! You're right, I didn't add .iteritems(). Editing response now

Comment: Your answer isn't wrong now but I don't know if this is what OP wants, the question is very unclear

Comment: @jamylak I assume that OP is looking for something to map a function onto all values of a dictionary, unfortunately python does not have that capability. You can use comprehension or a for loop over an iterator like I suggested, but there is no map() for dictionaries.

Comment: For python3 skip this solution, iteritems() does not exist